# TikZ Macro for Placing an "X" by Coordinate

Tags: tikz-pgf, macros, coordinates

I would like to make a TikZ macro that will:

1. Have an optional argument of coordinates
2. Place X centered at those coordinates.

Is this possible?

This is how I put two X's on a 10x10 grid manually. (I need a macro for when I have, say, 40 of them to place and they're all congruent, but more complex than an X.)

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}

\draw[gray] (-5,-5) grid (5,5);

\draw[line width =2pt] % x- and y-axes
 (-5,0)--(5,0)
 (0,-5)--(0,5);

\draw % Draws X as two paths, the way one normally would.
 (1.5,4.5)--(0.5,3.5)
 (0.5,4.5)--(1.5,3.5);

\draw % Draws the X as four "paths", all from the center of the X out.
 (-3,2)--(-3.5,2.5)
 (-3,2)--(-3.5,1.5)
 (-3,2)--(-2.5,1.5)
 (-3,2)--(-2.5,2.5);

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

How could I write a macro to save myself from having to write out the paths of those X's? Ideally, I'd like something like this:

```
\newcommand{\X}
 [1] % This optional argument would be the coordinates of the center of the X.
 {whatever goes in here would use the coordinates above to draw the X}

\X{(3,-2)} % This would place the X at (3,-2).
```

How can I make this work?

Comment: Is this always gonna be for a X-shaped figure?

Comment: For the purposes of this thread, yes, as it's a simple shape that works for the MWE. Eventually the shapes will be more complex, but I thought I'd start with a relatively simple one and start a new thread if I need one for those more complex shapes later.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use a `pic` path and define the command:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}


\tikzset{
  myex/.pic = {
    \draw 
      (-5mm,-5mm) -- (5mm,5mm)
      (-5mm,5mm) -- (5mm,-5mm);
  }
}
\newcommand\MyEx[1][(0,0)]{\pic at #1 {myex};}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}

\draw[gray] (-5,-5) grid (5,5);

\draw[line width =2pt] % x- and y-axes
 (-5,0)--(5,0)
 (0,-5)--(0,5);

\pic at (3,3) {myex};
\MyEx
\MyEx[(3,-2)]
\MyEx[(-3,2)]

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

In comments it has been mentioned that the length for the "X" might be a function of the coordinates specified as the origin; here's one simply way to achieve this using the `calc` library and the `let` syntax; the length of the "X" equals the length of the vector given as origin for the "X" (more complex dependencies can be achieved, but I selected this just for the example):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\newcommand\MyEx[1][(0,0)]{
  \draw 
    let 
    \p1=#1,
    \n1={veclen(\p1)} 
    in
    ( $ #1 + (225:0.5*\n1) $ ) -- ( $ #1 + (45:0.5*\n1) $ )
    ( $ #1 + (135:0.5*\n1) $ ) -- ( $ #1 + (-45:0.5*\n1) $ );
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[gray] (-5,-5) grid (5,5);

\draw[line width =2pt] % x- and y-axes
 (-5,0)--(5,0)
 (0,-5)--(0,5);

\MyEx
\MyEx[(0,3)]
\MyEx[(3.5,1.5)]
\MyEx[(1,1)]
\MyEx[(-1,-2)]
\MyEx[(-3,-1)]
\MyEx[(1,-3)]
\MyEx[(-3,3)]
\coordinate (aux) at (4,4);
\MyEx[(aux)]
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

The result:

[image]

Comment: Couple questions. (1) Where can I read more about this `\tikzset` thing? I just read the official TikZ/PGF manual and couldn't make sense of it, e.g the ` /,pic=` part. (2) Instead of using `(-5mm,5mm)` as absolute magnitudes, is there any way to make them a function of the optional coordinates entered?

Comment: @WeCanLearnAnything (1) See **Section 18.2 The Pic Syntax**. (2) Sure, but you would need to describe in more extent your intent (this seems like a topic for a new question).

Comment: @WeCanLearnAnything Please see my updated answer for an example in which the length depends now on the coordinates specified to place the "X".

Comment: @GonzaloMedina You may use `... let \p1 = #1, \n1={veclen(\p1)} in ...` to allow explicit coordinate (as `(0,0)`) and named coordinate (as `(a)`).

Comment: @PaulGaborit That's a very good suggestion; I've incorporated it into my answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution with a `cross out` shaped node from `shapes.misc` library. In next code, `mycross` style already fixes `node contents={}` and uses `at={#1}` option for setting node's center coordinate. And, as usual, if default settings doesn't like, change them according particular needs.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.misc}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[mycross/.style={cross out, draw, 
        inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt, 
        minimum size=1cm, node contents={}, at={#1}}]


\draw[gray] (-5,-5) grid (5,5);

\draw[line width =2pt] % x- and y-axes
 (-5,0)--(5,0)
 (0,-5)--(0,5);

\node[mycross={(2,4)}]; 
\node[mycross={(0,0)}];
\node[mycross={(-2,-3)}, minimum size=2cm, red, ultra thick];
\node[mycross={(1,-4)}, rotate=10];

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]